# using both class and typename in the operator overloading declaration

Tags: c++, oop, templates, linked-list, operator-overloading

I am a little bit confused by the use of typename in the declaration of the operator ++ below:

```
template<class T>
typename DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator& 
DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator::operator++() 
{ 
    // ToDo
    
}
```

I know they are interchangeable but is it also possible to use both of them like this?
or does this mean something different?

The definition in the header file is as follows: `Iterator& operator++();`

Comment: For this purpose `typename` may not be replaced by `class`. See linked duplicates. However the use of `class` in the template parameter may be replaced by `typename`.

Comment: could you elaborate more on the use of `typename` in this case please?

Comment: I have added back the original duplicate, which explains why `typename` before the return type is required in the first place. In short: `DoublyLinkedList<T>` depends on a template parameter and so the compiler can't know without the keyword whether or not `DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator` is going to be a type before instantiation of the template happens. `typename` disambiguates this.